# How to arrange the buttons to fill the profits?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a spending board with Bootstrap 4.
Right now that's what I did, and I want buttons to be displayed as in the picture below.
I have no idea how to do it ..

What I get right now:
[image: what i get right now..]

What I want to get in the end:
[image: what i want to get in the end]

```css
.btn-warning {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 85px;
}

.middel {
  background-color: #ff00008a;
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" style="border: 1px solid black;height: 85px;"> בוצע על ידי
      <select class="form-control">
        <option> moshe </option>
        <option> haim </option>
        <option> kobi </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 85px;"> באמצעות
      <select class="form-control">
        <option> moshe </option>
        <option> haim </option>
        <option> kobi </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> אוכל לבית </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> בילוים </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> אינטרנט חשמל וכבלים </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> ארנונה </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> ארנונה </button>
    <button class="col-6 middel">
                <h2>expense</h2>
                <div style="font-size: 120%; color: red"> <b>1900</b></div>
                <div style="font-size: 75%; color: green"><b> 3500</b></div>
            </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> חשבונות בית </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> הוצאות רפואיות </button><button class="col-3 btn btn-warning">
                חשבונות בית </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> חשבונות בית </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> חשבונות בית </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> חשבונות בית </button>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin: 5px;height: 75px;border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="col-4">
      בחר את תאריך ביצוע הפעולה :
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin: 5px;height: 75px; border: 1px solid black">
    <input class="col-12" type="text" placeholder="תאר את ההוצאה (לא חובה)">
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin: 5px;height: 75px; border: 1px solid black">
    <button class="btn btn-dark col-12"> הוסף </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Attaching photo after @connexo answer:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using  CSS grid. Please note that your HTML is actually invalid. `button` cannot contain either of `h2` and  `div`, only non-interactive [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.grid button {
  background-color: orange;
}

.grid .centercell {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-row: 2/5;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <button> אוכל לבית </button>
  <button> בילוים </button>
  <button> אינטרנט חשמל וכבלים </button>
  <button> ארנונה </button>
  <button> ארנונה </button>
  <button class="centercell">
    <span>expense</span>
    <span style="font-size: 120%; color: red"> <b>1900</b></span>
    <span style="font-size: 75%; color: green"><b> 3500</b></span>
  </button>
  <button> חשבונות בית </button>
  <button> הוצאות רפואיות </button><button>
  חשבונות בית </button>
  <button> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
  <button> חשבונות בית </button>
  <button> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
  <button> חשבונות בית </button>
  <button> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
  <button> חשבונות בית </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know you could make an element take up multiple cells like that with grid.  That is cool!

Comment: @ChayMizrahi It is fully responsive, since the column definitions use `fr` and the grid stretches to whatever the viewport is.

Comment: I'm sorry it does respond, but the width of the button doesn't match the width of the page.
I do not know `vw ` but trying to lower the width it did not give a good view ..
Joins a picture in the body of the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your html struct like this:

```css
.btn-warning {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 85px;
}

.middel {
  background-color: #ff00008a;
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" style="border: 1px solid black;height: 85px;"> בוצע על ידי
      <select class="form-control">
        <option> moshe </option>
        <option> haim </option>
        <option> kobi </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 85px;"> באמצעות
      <select class="form-control">
        <option> moshe </option>
        <option> haim </option>
        <option> kobi </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> אוכל לבית </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> בילוים </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> אינטרנט חשמל וכבלים </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> ארנונה </button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <button class="col-12 btn btn-warning"> ארנונה </button>
      <button class="col-12 btn btn-warning"> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
      <button class="col-12 btn btn-warning">
                חשבונות בית </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <button class="col-12 middel">
                <h2>expense</h2>
                <div style="font-size: 120%; color: red"> <b>1900</b></div>
                <div style="font-size: 75%; color: green"><b> 3500</b></div>
            </button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <button class="col-12 btn btn-warning"> חשבונות בית </button>
      <button class="col-12 btn btn-warning"> חשבונות בית </button>
      <button class="col-12 btn btn-warning"> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">


    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> הוצאות רפואיות </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> חשבונות בית </button>
    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> הוצאות רפואיות </button>


    <button class="col-3 btn btn-warning"> חשבונות בית </button>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin: 5px;height: 75px;border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="col-4">
      בחר את תאריך ביצוע הפעולה :
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin: 5px;height: 75px; border: 1px solid black">
    <input class="col-12" type="text" placeholder="תאר את ההוצאה (לא חובה)">
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin: 5px;height: 75px; border: 1px solid black">
    <button class="btn btn-dark col-12"> הוסף </button>
  </div>
</div>
```